# Multi-user Authentication Twitter OAuth Gem - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, twitter, oauth

My app connects to user's Twitter account and pulls the most recent tweets from their timeline. I've used a combination of [OAuth Twitter](https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter) strategy and the [Twitter GEM by Sferik](https://github.com/sferik/twitter).

To see how the app would handle multi-user authentication, I created two Twitter accounts and tried authenticating each in my app.

**My problem is that both accounts are seeing the same set of tweets** *(belonging to account #1).*

Here is my:

#### OAuth initiazlier:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_API_KEY'], ENV['TWITTER_API_SECRET']
    {
      :secure_image_url => 'true',
      :image_size => 'original',
      :authorize_params => {
      :force_login => 'true',
      }
    }
end
```

#### User self.from_omniauth(auth):

```
 def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      ...
      user.save
    end

  end
```

#### Call to pull tweets from model:

```
def whatever
  ..
  tweets = $[my_provider_variable].home_timeline
  ..
end
```

#### Twitter API Gem initializer:

```
 $[my_provider_variable] = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = ENV['TWITTER_API_KEY']
  config.consumer_secret     = ENV['TWITTER_API_SECRET']
  config.access_token        = ENV['TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN']
  config.access_token_secret = ENV['TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET']
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a different model that `belongs_to` your user, and add `has_many` in the user model. And store provider and uid in that model. Then loop through all children that the user has and send a request for tweets with the information stored in the new model. That way you can add as many accounts as you like.

In your code I believe that the problem is `first_or_create`. When a new account is linked, it creates a new user instead of adding the information to existing user.

Comment: Yep. I actually ended up adding `token` and `secret` columns to the users table.